# How do you partially apply a function with multiple arguments?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I want to partially apply a function with an array of arguments.  When I tried to use `apply()` on `_.partial()` I got a type error in lodash.

```
function test(){
  return ([]).join.call(arguments,' ')
}


var p = _.partial.apply(null,test,[1,2,3]) //Type Error in lodash


p(4) //should log "1 2 3 4"
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
_.partial(test, 1, 2, 3)
// equivalent to:
_.partial.apply(null, [test, 1, 2, 3])
```

Or dynamically:

```
var args = [1,2,3]

_.partial.apply(null, [test].concat(args))
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I couldn't see that!